# Why subprocess.run() freezes on certain application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Why subprocess.run() freezes on this application?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('eumdac.exe')
```

The app is from official source: https://gitlab.eumetsat.int/eumetlab/data-services/eumdac/-/releases/1.2.0

*Windows Binary*: https://gitlab.eumetsat.int/eumetlab/data-services/eumdac/uploads/ddc0cac2c969efa51f000f4a5eccca59/eumdac-1.2.0-win.zip

This is what I am getting by running it in cmd.exe:

```
(project_directory)>eumdac
usage: eumdac [-h] [--version] [--set-credentials ConsumerKey ConsumerSecret] [--debug]
              {describe,search,download,subscribe,tailor} ...

EUMETSAT Data Access Client

positional arguments:
  {describe,search,download,subscribe,tailor}
    describe            describe a collection or product
    search              search for products at the collection level
    download            download product(s) from a collection
    subscribe           subscribe a server for a collection
    tailor              tailoring product(s) from collection

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  --set-credentials ConsumerKey ConsumerSecret
                        permanently set consumer key and secret and exit, see https://api.eumetsat.int/api-key
  --debug               show backtrace for errors
```

PS. "cmd /c eumdac.exe" neither works.

Comment: Can't reproduce. `subprocess.run('eumdac.exe')` shows the _usage_ page plus this `CompletedProcess` instance in my _Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2486]_ and _Python 3.11.1_: `CompletedProcess(args='eumdac.exe', returncode=0)`. Did you try _Python_ library instead of  [Windows standalone binary](https://gitlab.eumetsat.int/eumetlab/data-services/eumdac/uploads/ddc0cac2c969efa51f000f4a5eccca59/eumdac-1.2.0-win.zip)? Please share both Windows and Python versions.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2130], Python 3.7.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess.run(['powershell', './eumdac.exe', '-h'])`

To capture the output, you can use the following format.

```py
output = subprocess.run(['powershell', './eumdac.exe', '-h'], capture_output=True)
print(output.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: still freezes, waits forever

Comment: What is displayed? or how do you recognize that it is foren?

Comment: nothing, it simply freezes on the "output =" line... doesn't go further, never ... you can download the exec yourself and check -> https://gitlab.eumetsat.int/eumetlab/data-services/eumdac/uploads/ddc0cac2c969efa51f000f4a5eccca59/eumdac-1.2.0-win.zip